# Unable to print the message using controller in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I just started learning Angular js, I created an module and controller in external js file,

```
 **External js file contains**
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);



myApp.contorller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to angular js";
});
```

Then I bound the controller in view like that

HTMl File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myModule">
    <head >
        <title>Learing Angular js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src= "scripts/custom.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body >{{50+30}}
        <div ng-controller="myController" >
    {{ message}}

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My message is not displayed in a view, It showing the full expression {{message}}, but 50+30 is working fine. What wrong's with my controller and module.

Comment: Before posting anything can you time to check your console for errors

Answer (score 4):

here is the error: "contorller"

change

```
myApp.contorller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to angular js"; });
```

to

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to angular js";
});
```